# Admin for multisite gives "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" with installation in subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory, multisite

I have a multisite-WP installation inside a nested subfolder `ftp.example.com/example.com/public_html/wp/` Everything is working front-end, and I can log in in admin using `example.com/wp/wp-admin` however when I click on "sites" to go to the sites.php page I get redirected to this page: `https://example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php`. This returns a 404 obviously, if I manually type `https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/network/sites.php` it works!

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

So I tried the following ...

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wp/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('COOKIEPATH', '/wp/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/wp/');
```

... and this gave me correct url `https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/network/sites.php`, however even with the cookiepath-settings It just loaded for a minute and then gave me a "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And in database `wp_option` are set to:

```
'Site url' -> 'example.com/wp/'

'Home' -> 'example.com'
```

So is it something above that's incorrect or is it .htaccess or something else?

Comment: have you tried >>https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress

Comment: I checked this but it doesn't seem to cover my issue since it has to do with the multisite installation (note only the files inside wp-admin/network/ seems to be effected with the redirect issue)

Answer (score 0):

When you set up Multi-site WP gives a load of lines that they tell you to put in the section that starts
`# BEGIN Wordpress` 
You'll notice that it should go between
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` 
and
`</IfModule>`

However, if you scroll up a bit above the # BEGIN Wordpress

you'll find that these two tags are there as well and mayp well read something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Backup the .htaccess file before you make any changes and delete the stuff above.
At this point not only will your theme be enabled but you'll also lose that annoying "Too many redirects" error message that you get on trying to connect to the site's dashboard.

If you think about it those two sections will conflict with each other causing the issue.